# Statically asserting the size of a std::array whose type is obtained using decltype from the return value of a member function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, decltype, static-assert

I want to write a free function that can automatically determine the type of its parameter, based on the return value of a member function of a class. Using `decltype`, that part is easy.

I *also* want to have a compile-time assertion to verify an assumption being made about that parameter type, and this is where my proposed solution falls apart.

Consider the following MCVE:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
   std::array<int, 10> Get();
};

void PrintFoos(const decltype(Foo().Get())& param)
{
    static_assert(param.size() == 10, "wrong size");
    for (const auto& i : param)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

GCC compiles the above code just fine, with nary a warning.

Clang, on the other hand, gripes:

```
error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(param.size() == 10, "wrong size");
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So does MSVC:

```
(13): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
(13): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
(13): note: see usage of 'param'
```

Why does GCC compile this fine, when other compilers reject it? Is there a GCC extension that I'm benefitting from to support this?

What does the language standard have to say about this? I am targeting C++17, but would also be interested in knowing if there are any changes from C++14.

**Bonus Question:** Is there a way that I can modify this code to make it work?  Obviously, the `static_assert` *should* fail if the `decltype` expression does not evaluate to a `std::array` type, since the `size()` member function would not be `constexpr`. I imagine there is a solution involving the addition of a template helper function, but I'd rather not add another function definition unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with the way that `std::array::size` is defined. `size` is meant to be a member function so `param.size()` is a `constexpr` if `param` is a `constexpr` (which it isn't). Maybe GCC defined `size` as `static` so that `param` doesn't need to be a `constexpr` for `param.size()` to be `constexpr`.

Comment: Nope. That's not it. I just checked libc++ and libstdc++. I'm not certain but I think this could be a GCC bug.

Comment: Does it really have to be `decltype(Foo().Get())`? If you could just take an `std::array<T, N>`, you could infer the size of the array from the argument type…

Comment: @Michael That would require me to hard-code the length of the `std::array` in that function's signature, which I don't want to do. I only want to maintain the size in one place (the class interface), *not* in the free function. It's not DRY, in other words.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say you don't want to maintain the size in two different places, yet what your question is all about is this `static_assert` that compares the size to a hard-coded value in the place where you now say you don't want to maintain the size as a hardcoded value!? If the array type is already derived from what `Foo` does, then what for is the `static_assert` even necessary? It cannot possibly be not the size of the thing that `Foo::Get()` returns because if it were then the function would never be called!?

Comment: @Michael Yeah…that's a good point. The actual function body (i.e., not the simplified version shown in the MCVE here) makes some assumptions about the length of the array, and I want to ensure that any incorrect assumptions are caught at compile time. This should catch the case where the class interface is changed, but the free function is forgotten and not updated. I guess I could just have the size as part of the type in both places, and let a potential type-mismatch error be the consistency check. Should probably reconsider. Either way, still interested in what is the correct behavior.

Comment: The problem clang/msvc has with it is the fact `params` is a *reference*.  All that talk about "`.size()` is not constexpr if params is not" is nonsense.  If you do `decltype(Foo().Get()) test = {};` then `test.size()` is `consteval`.  The problem is that it is a reference, and there may be issues with that, not that it isn't constexpr.

Answer (score 6):

I believe clang and the others (icc and MSVC) are technically correct here and GCC is wrong. A [*static_assert-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:static_assert-declaration) takes a *constant-expression* [[expr.const]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2). I believe the relevant C++17 wording for the case at hand should be [[expr.const]/2.11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11):

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - […]
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;
> - […]

The expression in your `static_assert` above clearly does exactly that, however (`param` is an *id-expression* that refers to a variable of reference type, none of the exceptions apply). Thus, it is not a constant expression, and the program is ill-formed [[dcl.dcl]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#6). The relevant wording in the C++14 standard seems to be identical. I woud consider this a bug in GCC.

If you can change your function into a template, you could simply infer the size:

```
template <int N>
void PrintFoos(const std::array<int, N>& param)
{
    …
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to make everything depend on `Foo`, you could also just define a public constant and derive the array type etc. from that:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr auto size = 10;
    std::array<int, size> Get();
};

void PrintFoos(const decltype(Foo().Get())& param)
{
    static_assert(Foo::size == 10, "wrong size");
}
```

And, of course, you could use a helper template:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t deduce_array_size = 0U;

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t deduce_array_size<std::array<T, N>> = N;

template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t deduce_array_size<T&> = deduce_array_size<T>;

template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t deduce_array_size<T&&> = deduce_array_size<T>;
```

and then

```
void PrintFoos(const decltype(Foo().Get())& param)
{
    static_assert(deduce_array_size<decltype(param)> == 10, "wrong size");
}
```

Finally, yet another option (inspired by the comment by Yakk - Adam Nevraumont below) would be to simply create a prvalue of the array type in your constant expression and ask that for its size:

```
static_assert(std::decay_t<decltype(param)>{}.size() == 10, "wrong size");
```

Comment: That, to me, is a defect in the standard; a variable of type `std::decay_t<decltype(param)>` can have `.size()` called on it no problem, because `.size()` doesn't *really* need its object for arrays....

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont fair enough, I would agree with you, it's what the standard says at the moment, however…unless I overlooked something, of course…

Comment: Thanks, this is a fantastic answer, and essentially what I was looking for. I'm afraid that my standards-ese is rather weak, so I'm a bit confused by your (and Adam's) observation that the problem really lies with the expression being a *reference*. If that's the case, why does changing the parameter's type to `const std::array<int, 10>& param` not create a problem when doing `static_assert(params.size() == 10)`? It is still a reference in that case. What is the difference between the use of `decltype` and the explicit type specification?

Comment: @CodyGray If I change it from `const decltype(Foo().Get())& param` to `const std::array<int, 10>& param`, I get the exact same error message in clang. And I should, because there's absolutely no difference between these two versions. The type is exactly the same in both cases.